# Max number of viewers for different types of Flash Media Server instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, flash, amazon-cloudfront, flash-media-server

I'm looking [on Adobe Flash Media Server webiste, under Instance Types](http://www.adobe.com/products/amazon-web-services/pricing.html)

For each type of instance, it lists the "Simultaneous connections".

If the instance I want lists "1000 RTMFP", does that mean that I can only have a maximum of 1000 people viewing my live stream at one time?* What happens to person #1001 if there are already 1000 people watching? **Or, does RTMFP mean something else?**

I am using [Amazon Web Services and Amazon Cloudfront to stream my event](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/FeaturedArticles/latest/index.html?LiveStreamingUsingAmazonCloudFront.html), which use FMS.

No one in the free support (or forums) at AWS and Adobe seems to know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a license limit set by Adobe:

> I don't work for Adobe but can confirm that these limits are imposed by them. It basically means that for using the P2P feature in FMS you have certain connection limits imposed depending on instance type. Even though Flash Player clients connect to one another in a P2P mode they also hold a connection open to FMS to exchange fingerprints and for potential rollover from RTMFP (P2P, UDP based) to RTMP (server-client, TCP).
>
> The underlying license type applied to the AMI is FMS Enterprise Edition, but with the said limits on P2P connections.

(Source: [AWS forum post from Stefan Richter](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=222669).)

Comment: Thanks for finding that. So, the number, say 1000 RTMFP connections, can be interpreted to mean 1000 viewers, or people watching, at once?

Comment: As I understand it, yes.  RTMFP connections have a peer-to-peer component, so the amount of viewers isn't (as) limited by the processing power of the server.